# Sorting a list of objects by an attribute's substring

Tags: java, spring-boot, sorting, substring, backend

I have a list of objects containing an attribute date that looks like this "Thu Oct 26 2023"

I want to sort those objects by their substring(8,9) which is 26 in this case.

I've looked up parsing the substring to int and using a Comparator and then Collections.sort but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: yes - parse the `String` attribute to a `LocalDate` attribute, and sort on day of month.  Also, what should be sort order if the list contains multiple months for the same day?

Comment: The List will only return days for a month. Is that format acceptable for localdate?

Comment: `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.attr.substring(8, 9)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to sort those objects by their substring(8,9) which is 26 in
> this case.

`substring(8, 9)` will not provide 26 from `"Thu Oct 26 2023"`, it will provide **`2`**. To get `26` you would need `substring(8, 10)`. At this stage, it's hard to say whether or not the *days of the month* will always be in the format of two digits (as in `01`, `02`, `30`, etc) or will it possibly be in the format of single digits as well (as in `1`, `2`, `30`, etc).

In the provided date (`"Thu Oct 26 2023"`), one thing that is for sure is the fact that, if the actual string date format is always followed, there will always be a white-space between the date components. Based on this fact, it would be more beneficial to split the date components to collect the actual *day of the month* regardless of how many digits it may be.

```
// `hireDate` is an instance variable within the `MyObject` class:
// `list` is a List of MyObject instances, ex: List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.sort(java.util.Comparator.comparing(e -> e.hireDate.split("\\s")[2]));
```

This however will not sort properly. Consider the fact that the date is a string and string represented integer numbers such as the *day of month* and the *year* do not sort the same as actual Integer (int or long type) numbers, for example, to sort string values of: "10", "3", "1", and "5", you would think that the sorted result would be: `"1", "3", "5", "10"` but...it won't be. It will be sorted as `"1", "10", "3", "5"`. If the above values were actual int or long type integer values: `10, 3, 1, and 5` then these numbers would indeed be sorted in ascending order as `1, 3, 5, 10` as expected.

To get around this little problem we can convert the String represented integer values to BigInteger which accepts string values and will allow the sort to be carried out properly:

```
// `hireDate` is an instance variable within the `MyObject` class:
// `list` is a List of MyObject instances, ex: List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.sort(java.util.Comparator.comparing(e -> 
            new java.math.BigInteger(e.hireDate.split("\\s")[2])));
```

would result in a sorted list of: `"1", "3", "5", "10"`.

To see the above code in action, create a new project and create a SortByDay class with a `main()` method and copy paste the following runnable code into it. Be sure to read the comments in code:

```
public class SortByDay {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* App started this way to avoid the need for statics
           unless we really want them:        */
        new SortByDay().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        // Create a java.util.List of MyObject instances:
        java.util.List<MyObject> objList = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        objList.add(new MyObject("Tom Jones", 66, "Thu Oct 4 2023", 32.50));
        objList.add(new MyObject("Tracey Johnson", 59, "Tue Oct 10 2023", 31.00));
        objList.add(new MyObject("Dave Simpson", 30, "Wed Oct 1 2023", 43.75));
        
        /* Display the List before sorting in Ascending order
           by day of month:            */
        System.out.println("Before Sorting:\n===============");
        for (MyObject o : objList) {
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        }
        System.out.println();
        
        /* Sort the List of MyObject based on the day of month 
           in each instance contained within the List:     */
        sortListedObjectByDayOfMonth(objList);
        
        /* Display the List after sorting in Ascending order
           by day of month:            */
        System.out.println("After Sorting:\n==============");
        for (MyObject o : objList) {
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        }
    }
    
    public void sortListedObjectByDayOfMonth(java.util.List<MyObject> list) {
        list.sort(java.util.Comparator.comparing(e -> 
                new java.math.BigInteger(e.hireDate.split("\\s")[2])));
    }
    
    public class MyObject {
        
        // Instance (member) variables:
        private String name;
        private int age;
        private String hireDate;
        private double wage;

        // Constructor:
        public MyObject(String name, int age, String hireDate, double wage) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.hireDate = hireDate;
            this.wage = wage;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + ", " + age + ", \"" + hireDate + "\", $" 
                                + String.format("%.02f", wage);
        }
    }    
}
```

Console Window output should look something like this when the code is run:

```
Before Sorting:
===============
Tom Jones, 66, "Thu Oct 4 2023", $32.50
Tracey Johnson, 59, "Tue Oct 10 2023", $31.00
Dave Simpson, 30, "Wed Oct 1 2023", $43.75

After Sorting:
==============
Dave Simpson, 30, "Wed Oct 1 2023", $43.75
Tom Jones, 66, "Thu Oct 4 2023", $32.50
Tracey Johnson, 59, "Tue Oct 10 2023", $31.00
```